# Android: Get Seconds When Stop CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, countdowntimer

Having a issue here I have a countdown Timer, When a specific button is pressed I want the Timer to stop and be able to get the Seconds of when it was stopped though I can't seem to find anything within the documentation to access the secons in my onclick listener here's my code:

```
final CountDownTimer time1 = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { //30 Seconds 

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }

             public void onFinish() {

             }
          }.start();

          btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(time1 != null)
                    {
                        time1.cancel();
                        //Need to Get Seconds here
                    }
            }
        });
```

any help would be really appreciated as I've tried to call the onTick method within my button but I just get errors. I have seen similar questions to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve it. You could subclass `CountDownTimer`, store in a private member the time and add  a `getter` to return this value